# Ionic Framework Using Phonegap Facebook Connect Plugin API cant make pagination of friends work

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

My ionic view uses infinite scroll for friends view and here is the controller:

```
$scope.friends = [];
$scope.after = "";

var getFriends = function(after)
    {
        var friends = $q.defer();
        UserService.getUser().then(function (d) {

        var url = '/me?fields=taggable_friends&access_token='+ d.authResponse.accessToken;
        if (after != "")
        {
            url += "&limit=25&after="+after;
        }
        facebookConnectPlugin.api(url, null,
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                friends.resolve(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                friends.reject(response);
            }
        );
    });
    return friends.promise;
};

$scope.loadMoreData = function()
{
    getFriends($scope.after).then(function(d)
    {
        $scope.friends = $scope.friends.concat(d.taggable_friends.data);
        $scope.after = d.taggable_friends.paging.cursors.after;
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });

};
```

The first call is executed to url:
"/me?fields=taggable_friends&access_token=myAccessToken" and I receive an object as follows:

```
object
    {
        id: "string"
        taggable_friends
        {
            data
            {
                [n]objects
            }
            paging
            {
                cursors
                {
                    after: "string"
                    before: "string"
                }
            next: "string"
        }
    }
}
```

The second call url is:
/me?fields=taggable_friends&access_token=myAccessToken&after=QWFKVko1NlJmWUREajBTeERZAbmFJUzlLUWp5ZA3o5cDA5SWVHc1BKblJ6ODMweDd4TzdxMlJyOTdKNDlUb0NHQWl1M3FJbXdjbkpWc2NwSlNiS25peV8zYV9vdTdGbXFPMG5YNnpDSW1jWkVNX0EZD

In both cases I get the same object. With exactly the same Data. When I use browser for the 2 URLs, i get different (correct) data.

I even tried to request /me?fields=taggable_friends&access_token=myAccessToken&after=QWFKVko1NlJmWUREajBTeERZAbmFJUzlLUWp5ZA3o5cDA5SWVHc1BKblJ6ODMweDd4TzdxMlJyOTdKNDlUb0NHQWl1M3FJbXdjbkpWc2NwSlNiS25peV8zYV9vdTdGbXFPMG5YNnpDSW1jWkVNX0EZD in first call, but still I get the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution!

I don't know what the reason is, but API call like "/me?fields=taggable_friends&access_token=..." don't work when "after" parameter is added.

***It should be used this way: "/me/taggable_friends?access_token=...", this way it works.***